# Can we convert/rewrite sslprotocol TLSv1.0 coming from client to TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 and forward with sslprotocol as TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 using Apache

Tags: java, apache, ssl, proxy, forward

I want to convert TLSv1.0 to TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2, So that my outgoing request from my Proxy server is TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2. I can use Apache server.

Can someone Please Help !!

Any kind of Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: For what purpose? And where is this proxy? at the client? or the server?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have two web application one is on java6 and other is on java8. We make Java8 side app beast protected by limiting sslprotocol to TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2. But Java6 side app is vulnerable, this support TLSv1.0 (this protocol is vulnerable) and hence it cannot communicate with java8 side app. So My understanding is if its possible (java8 side) to convert TLS1.0 to TLSv1.2/TLSv1.1 and send it to Java8 app, Because Java8 app wont understand TLSv1.0. Proxy can be configured at server at Java8 side. Or please suggest any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: Just to add to above , Proxy could be reverse proxy at java8 side

Comment: So your question is pointless. Securing the short path from your own proxy to your own webapp doesn't secure the entire connection. The part between the client and your proxy is still vulnerable. What you need to do is (a) stop your *server* from *accepting * TLSv1.0, and (b) upgrade the clients.

Comment: Surely we have that option to update other client to java8 i.e. TLS 1.2, But since we have many Users on java6 and after upgrading to Java8 still he should be able to receive communication from other existing java6 users(which they would not have upgraded to java8 due to xyz reasons). As a workaround i wanted to have this at java8 side. If you understand what i actually mean. Have tried all options ,but failed :(

Comment: You haven't addressed my comment. It's pointless. When the clients upgrade they will get more security. Until they do, they can't. Securing a couple of feet of Ethernet doesn't add any value.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know it seems pointless and vulnerable. But until they upgrade to Java8 they should be able to communicate with Java8 Users thats the requirement. Upgrading is always an option to be specific to your pointless. But if its possible it would be better for existing users without changing anything.